# Slick - arrows with name of prev/next slide

Tags: javascript, carousel, slick.js, arrows

I am trying to do arrows with titles of prev/next slides (using the data att "data-slide-name"). I searched the internet through and I didn't find anything I needed. I have one slide(Name 1), prev slide(Cat), next slide(Dog). I want to show slide names in arrows. For example, I attach codepen (with scss):

https://codepen.io/michal-gajda/pen/MWwzvvp

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide">
    <div class="slide__title">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="slide__items">
        <div class="slide__item" data-slide-name="Cat">
            <div class="slide__box">
                <div class="slide__inner">
                    <div class="slide__content">
                        <h3>Cat</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum ..</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__item" data-slide-name="Name1">
            <div class="slide__box">
                <div class="slide__inner">
                    <div class="slide__content">
                        <h3>Name1</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum.. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__item" data-slide-name="Dog">
            <div class="slide__box">
                <div class="slide__inner">
                    <div class="slide__content">
                        <h3>Dog</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum... </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.slide__items').slick({
dots: false,
arrows: true,
infinite: true,
speed: 800,
slidesToShow: 1,
adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

**SCSS**

```
.slide {
padding: 0 20px;
background-color: #EEE8E2;

&__title {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 70px;

    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #7A6857;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 1;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }
}

&__watermark-text {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 4% 0 0 -5%;

    svg {}
}

&__items {}

&__item {
    padding: 70px 20px 70px+20px+70px 20px;
    outline: transparent;
}

&__box {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 13px 16px 6px rgba(149, 135, 121, 0.25);  
}

&__inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

&__content {
    width: 43%;
    padding: 90px 60px;

    h1,h2,h3 {
       font-size: 24px;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       margin: 0 0 1em 0;
       letter-spacing: 0.1em;
       line-height: 1;
    }

    p {
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
}

&__img {
    width: 57%;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}

&__buttons {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 0.7em;
}

&__btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    padding: 0.75em 0;
    color: #B19777;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.slick-arrow {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #CEBDAD;
    outline: transparent;
    transition: 0.3s;

    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
    z-index: 50;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #B19777;
    }
}

.slick-prev {
    left: -20px;
}

.slick-next {
    right: -20px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `init afterChange` events

```
$('.slide__items').on('init afterChange', function(e, slick){
  let currentSlick = $('.slick-current.slick-active', slick.$slideTrack)
  let prevName = currentSlick.prev().data('slide-name')
  let nextName = currentSlick.next().data('slide-name')

  slick.$prevArrow.text(prevName)
  slick.$nextArrow.text(nextName)
});
```

**Working Demo**

https://codepen.io/aswinkumar863/pen/abOQLVx

Comment: Your demo works great, but it doesn't work for me (local). It's probably because I have more than 1 per page. I tried to adjust using .find for slides and their arrows. Would you please help me treat it for more slides on the page?